# Add Comma between Multiple return Values

Tags: xml, xquery

I got an XML which looks like:

```
<Student>
    <SSN>630-44-3532</SSN>
    <Name>
        <firstName>Ali</firstName>
        <lastName>Daria</lastName>
    </Name>
            ...
    <Email>Ali@yahoo.com</Email>
    <Email>Ali@hotmail.com</Email>
</Student>
```

As we have multiple  nodes, when I execute an XQuery to get the email info as a whole, separated by a comma, I don't know what to do.

Here is the expected output:

```
<email> Alexander@yahoo.com, Alexander@gmail.com </email>
```

Comment: Judging from your posts you must be a hacker/spammer/virus kind of guy/gal one of those types. Don't expect much help from good, hard working people. Hopefully I am wrong.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete, short and easy one-liner XPath expression solution. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use**:

```
/*/Email/concat(.,
                if(not(position()=last()))
                 then ', '
                 else ()
                )
```

Comment: @SSB: `position()` is a standard XPath function. It gives us the position of the context item after the name test of the location step and any necessary deduplication has been performed. You may read the official definition in the XPath 1.0 W3C specification: http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-position

Answer (score 1):

Use XPath 2.0/XQuery 1.0 [fn:string-join()](http://www.w3.org/TR/2007/REC-xpath-functions-20070123/#func-string-join) function.

Brief from http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/#string-join

> #### string-join
>
> ```
> fn:string-join($arg1 as xs:string*, $arg2 as xs:string) as xs:string
> ```
>
> Summary: Returns a `xs:string` created
>   by concatenating the members of the
>   `$arg1` sequence using `$arg2` as a
>   separator. If the value of `$arg2` is
>   the zero-length string, then the
>   members of `$arg1` are concatenated
>   without a separator.